# problem with basemap installation in Conda (MacOs)

Tags: python

I am trying to install basemap in Conda by using the following command

```
conda install -c anaconda basemap
```

However I get the following error

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

How can I fix it? Because I am trying to plot NETCDF4 files into a map. Basically I am trying to construct a heat map to see the temperatures. Is there any other package I can use in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still needed, but running this:

```
conda update -all --yes
```

and then subsequently running:

```
-c conda-forge basemap
```

worked for me when I had run into the same problem.

Comment: Second command seems to have only arguments without actual program. is it `conda update -c conda-forge...` or `conda something-else`?